# passing parameters to anonymous functions Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener, anonymous-function

I could not understand why you do not need to pass the parameter `name` to the anonymous function inside the `addEventListener`. Why do you need to pass `e` , but not `name`.
I mean line 6 at the end of the line, `function(e)`

```
let btn = document.querySelector(".test-btn");
  function firstFunction(e,name){
    e.preventDefault();
    btn.innerHTML = name;
  }
  btn.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    firstFunction(e, "Elon");
  });
```

Comment: Because that function is a callback from the event listener, which only provides the event object as the first positional argument. The `name` argument is used by your `firstFunction` method.

Comment: You don't "pass e", it's the browser that passes it, just because of how the event is defined in the specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function parameters allow a block at some position, let's say block A, to send information to a function block at some other position, let's say Block B. When you pass a parameter, information can flow from A to B if A sends an argument and B accepts an argument.

Here, part of the information being sent is initialized inside the click callback:

```
btn.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  firstFunction(e, "Elon");
});
```

The `e`, the click event, is initialized by the browser and sent to the callback. But then the `"Elon"` string is created inside the callback. Finally, the callback does `firstFunction(e, "Elon")` to pass both pieces of information to the `firstFunction`, or the B block.

Because the extra information being passed along is created inside the click callback, and not by the *caller* of the click callback, the click callback only accepts one parameter, the event.